# this does not access http response object:property does not exist on type Object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have response object i just assigned to "this" object.

```
private data: Object = {};

this.http.post('url', { })
    .subscribe(
        res => {
            console.log(res);
            this.data = res;

            if(this.data.datacentersinfo.length) {}

...
```

If I access `datacentersinfo` object it saying property `datacentersinfo` does not exist on type Object. Because of this error, I  am not able to generate the dist folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several solutions :

1 - type your data to any and don't instanciate it :

```
private data: any;
```

2 - change your condition :

```
if(this.data && this.data.datacentersinfo && this.data.datacentersinfo.length) {}
```

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: dist is generated!!

Answer (score 2):

i suggest you make use of strongly type object and do as below

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, 
             Response, ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';

GetAllCriteria(): Observable<Array<ClassName>> {
    let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this._http.get(this.apiUrl + "/GetAllCriteria",
                       options).subscribe(response => response.json());
}
```

Comment: If he is using the HttpClient, it won't work though.

Comment: @trichetriche - add this at top   import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, 
                 Response, ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';

Comment: @trichetriche - why ? do you think there is no data ..or its null..this is needed i think res.json(); to convert row json data to object of typescript

Comment: No, because Angular will deprecate the Http module in favor of HttpClient, and HttpClient already parses the responses to JSON. It's in their HTTP guide :)

Comment: See @Wesley's answer, he explains it !

Comment: @trichetriche - - hmm i have used old libarary i started coding iwht angualr 4 ....

Answer (score 1):

I'll post both ways to do this. First the old way (which looks like how you're trying to do it), then the preferred way using HTTP Client

**Old HTTP**

```
private data: Object = {};
this.http.post('url', { })
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .subscribe((res:any) => {
        console.log(res);
        this.data = res;
        if(this.data.datacentersinfo.length) {}
});
```

**HTTP Client**

```
private data: Object = {};
    this.http.post<any>('url', { })            
        .subscribe((res:any) => {
            console.log(res);
            this.data = res;
            if(this.data.datacentersinfo.length) {}
    });
```

I'm not doing this the best way it should be done, you should create a service component that handles the HTTP request, then call that service from the component and subscribe to it's response there.